# Creating numpy array of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional numpy array where the data type is a matrix. So, I would like to be able to store a 3x3 numpy matrices into a multi-dimensional array. For example, I would like to create a numpy array of size 100 x 100 x 100, so when I refer to an index like:

```
x [10, 10, 10] <- should return a 3x3 numpy matrix
```

I can do something like:

```
x = np.array((100, 100, 100), np.matrix)
```

However, I am not sure how to define the size of the matrix in this case. Another option is to do something like:

```
x = np.array((100, 100, 100, 3, 3))
```

However, this way I am not able to take advantage of the matrix object class and its functions.

[EDIT]

One thing I now realised is that I can cast an array to numpy matrix. So, using something like:

```
x = np.array((100, 100, 100, 3, 3))
a = np.matrix(x[1, 1, 1])
```

However, I wonder if there is a more direct way.

[MORE EDIT]

After reading comments, it seems the numpy matrix class is not really that useful. I can do something like the following to compute the inverse, for example:

```
x = np.array((100, 100, 100, 3, 3))
a = np.matrix(x[1, 1, 1])
a_inv = np.linalg.inv(a)
```

Comment: "this way I am not able to take advantage of the matrix object class and its functions" What's the problem? You're creating a 5 dimension matrix, everything should work fine as far as numpy is concerned

Comment: Which matrix functions are you trying to use? `np.linalg` provides most functionality of matrices without needing the matrix type.

Comment: Really simple things like inverses. Ok, I am not very familiar with the np.linalg package, so I guess it can work directly with the numpy arrays. @toasted_flakes: I thought the numpy matrix is a more specialised object (compared to numpy arrays) and things like matrix inverses needed the matrix object. However, thanks for pointing me to the lining package.

Comment: Numpy matrix is not useful in most of the cases. Matrix multiplication (for example) can be achieved by the `dot` function as `a.dot(b)` where `a` and `b` are two 2D numpy arrays (not matrix). Additionally, as @Till Hoffmann pointed out, you don't need to cast `x` to matrix, you can just use `np.linalg.inv(x[1,1,1])`.

Comment: To add to @iluengo's comment, `np.linalg.inv` uses broadcasting rules, i.e. you can invert a load of arrays at once http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html .

Comment: Oh wow...this is exactly what I need!